# Liferay 5.2.3 /tomcat 6 SSL installation steps for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: tomcat, ssl, liferay, ssl-certificate

I have created CSR file with following location:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin"

My liferay installation is having jre folder too (\tomcat-6.0.18\jre1.5.0_17). I am not sure which one of the above two JRE is the right place to generate CSR.

For Apache Tomcat server this link is very helpful :
http://www.entrust.net/ssl-technical/webserver.cfm

But to configure the same in Liferay it is difficult for me. If anyone can provide me steps specific for liferay it will very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is make Liferay available through https, you'll just need to configure your application server (e.g. tomcat) based on the existing documentation that you link. Liferay adds nothing to this and doesn't handle https in this case.

The only situation where you might need to do more is when you access other servers through https from Liferay (e.g. for remote-publishing through https) to establish a trust between Liferay and that other tomcat/liferay. ([This blog article](https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/setting-up-remote-staging-through-https) might help you for remote staging)

In order to find out which java is used, you might want to refer to your tomcat configuration, e.g. in bin/setenv.sh, or to the process list which might show you which version it runs. Or just remove one of the JREs and work with the definitive one and only that you have (it's a good idea to know what exactly is running on your server anyways)

Also, please consider updating to a more recent version. 5.2.3 is outdated by almost 3 years now

Comment: Thanks Olaf for the answer. I have implement SSL on Liferay successfully. I have used "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin" location for keytool command and followed the steps in given on this link: http://www.entrust.net/ssl-technical/webserver.cfm. After all keytool commands, SSL information is updated in server.xml and restarted tomcat server. The detailed information given on your blog is really helpful.